# Erro ao publicar o UWP na LOJA WINDOWS

Tags: windows, xamarin-forms, uwp, microsoft

Estou com o seguinte erro ao publicar na loja Windows (microsoft).

> API CreateFileW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application
>   type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API

Como remover o kernel32.dll???